Auth0 token - access token missing payload / is empty
I am testing my Spring OAuth Client with Auth0's authorization service.
I've created a simple 'Regular Web App' in Auth0, but the returned access token has no payload, it is null.
Auth0 Config

Spring Config
My authorization setup in Spring is like this:

But the returned access token is missing a payload.
Auth0 docs
There is something in the Auth0 docs that mentions setting an audience parameter in a token request.
https://community.auth0.com/t/what-is-the-audience/71414
Spring Config 2
I have done that.

But get the same result.
Can someone help?
